# Fixing up BAC program

Tags: c

Looking for some help with fixing up this program that calculates BAC and says whether or not you're alright to drive. I'm having some trouble with the last 3 scanf statements not running and with infinite prints of the statement saying if you're alright to drive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{

float drinks;
float shot = 1.5;
int beer = 12;
int wine = 5;
float floz;
float alcohol;
float weight;
float hours;
float bac;




printf("\nEnter beer if you drank beer, wine if you drank wine, and shot if you drank shots: ");
scanf(" %f.", &drinks);

printf("\nEnter how many fluid ounces of alcohol your drank: ");
scanf(" %f.", &floz);

printf("\nEnter your weight in pounds: ");
scanf(" %f.", &weight);

printf("\nEnter how long you've been drinking in hours: ");
scanf(" %f.", &hours);



do {
    alcohol = shot * floz * .4;
} while (drinks == shot);

do {
    alcohol = beer * floz * .05;
} while (drinks == beer);

do {
    alcohol = wine * floz * .12;
} while (drinks == wine);


bac = ((alcohol * 5.14) / (weight * .73)) - (.015 * hours);

printf("Your BAC is %f.\n", bac);


while (bac <= .03) {
    printf("You are ok to drive.\n");
}

while (.04 <= bac <= .08) {
printf("You may drive but it would be unsafe.\n");
}

while (bac >= .09) {
    printf("You are guaranteed a DUI if pulled over.\n");
}



return 0;

    }
```

Comment: what if `drinks == shot` is true? it will in infinite loop. check other `do..while` in same manner.

Comment: The last 3 `while`s should be changed into `if`.

Comment: Try with `if` condition instead of `while`...

Comment: Is there no way to use while like this? The assignment wants us to use while, for, and do while loops.

Comment: If someone types `beer` in response to the first prompt, the `scanf()` for a `float` will fail, and every subsequent input looking for a number will also fail, and you'll get gibberish out of your program — boring, repetitive gibberish.  You should check each `scanf()` return value to ensure it successfully converted the value.  You might consider a loop around each prompt and input operation so you go back (for a limited number of times) after a failed input.  You might also have a loop within that loop to read to the end of the line before repeating the  input/prompt/read cycle.

Comment: Your calculation loops are either done once or an infinite number of times because you never change the tested variables within the body of the loop.  Your output loops are either done zero times or an infinite number of times because you never change the tested variables within the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>// for strcmp

int main() 
{

char drinks[5];// you need a string not a float
float shot = 1.5;
int beer = 12;
int wine = 5;
float floz;
float alcohol;
float weight;
float hours;
float bac;




printf("\nEnter beer if you drank beer, wine if you drank wine, and shot if you drank shots: ");
scanf("%s", drinks);// scanning string

printf("\nEnter how many fluid ounces of alcohol your drank: ");
scanf(" %f", &floz);

printf("\nEnter your weight in pounds: ");
scanf(" %f", &weight);

printf("\nEnter how long you've been drinking in hours: ");
scanf(" %f", &hours);


//compare the input and word using strcmp
if(strcmp(drinks,"shot")==0)        alcohol = shot * floz * .4;


else if(strcmp(drinks,"beer")==0)
    alcohol = beer * floz * .05;


else if(strcmp(drinks,"wine")==0)
    alcohol = wine * floz * .12;



bac = ((alcohol * 5.14) / (weight * .73)) - (.015 * hours);

printf("Your BAC is %f.\n", bac);

// no need to loop
if (bac <= .03) 
    printf("You are ok to drive.\n");
// your condition dosen't do what you think
else if (bac >= .04 && bac <= .08) 
printf("You may drive but it would be unsafe.\n");
// use else as it is sure that bac > .08
else
    printf("You are guaranteed a DUI if pulled over.\n");

return 0;
    }
```